# I have an api call that I need to invoke before the second render after it receive new props

Tags: reactjs

getDerivedStateFromProps doesnt allow me to invoke `this` function to call an API. The component accept item id and with that id i need to call api before render.

I've tried calling api in componentDidUpdate, doesnt work since its after render. componentWillReceiveProps invoke api call before the actual props receive.

```
class Recipe extends PureComponent{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {isLoading:true}
    }
    componentDidUpdate(){
            console.log(this.props.isActive)
            this.getRecipe(this.props.isActive);
    }

    getRecipe = async(id='47032')=>{
        try {
          const key = 'apikey';
          const res = await axios.get(`https://www.food2fork.com/api/get?key=${key}&rId=${id}`);
          console.log(res.data)

            const get_ingredients = res.data.recipe.ingredients;
            const newGet_ingredients = this.parseIngredients(get_ingredients);
            res.data.recipe.ingredients = newGet_ingredients;
            this.Recipe = res.data
            this.setState({
                isLoading:false
            })

        }
        catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
            alert('Something went wrong :(')
        }

    }

    render(){
        console.log(this.Recipe)
        if(!this.state.isLoading)
        return(
        <div className="recipe">
            api data
        </div>)
        else return null  
    }
}
```

Comment: With compoenentDidUpdate api is call after react update dom with the old api id. so everything was delay by one id

Answer (score 1):

Try adding an if condition inside the componentDidUpdate to check whether isActive changed or not

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
    if(prevProps.isActive !== this.props.isActive){
        this.getRecipe(this.props.isActive);
    }        
}
```

this would only call the getRecipe function once the props value of isActive change